# Issue : Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, datasource

Trying to connect spring code with to SQL Server database using Microsoft driver via Datasource.

**application-context.xml:**

```
  <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>
```

**Property config:**

```
database.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
database.url=jdbc\:jtds\:sqlserver\://DB_ip:DB_Port/MyDB;instance=Some_Ins;integratedSecurity=true
database.username=
database.password=
```

**Error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in file [xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
  ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in file [xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
```

**Edited**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
            at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:97)
            at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:67)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:170)
            at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
          at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
            at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1797)
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1755)
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:247)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:373)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:358)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
            ... 39 more
```

Unable to identify the root cause..

Comment: Why downvote..Please explain to that , if any thing missed , can be added.

Comment: which dbms you using?

Comment: Have you actually read the stack trace? You are using hibernate and haven't told hibernate what the dialect is... Hence it tries to use the connection, but apparently it cannot connect. You try to use properties but to do so you need to add a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` or use `<context:property-placeholder />` else your `${..}` aren't going to be replaced. What is exactly wrong cannot be told because you haven't posted everything necessary but only snippets.

Comment: @M.Deinum I already had that in place and replacing is working fine..As well as I have manually placed the values with their corresponding property holders.Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Make sure that your username/password is really correct and that your URL is correct. Also what is with all the slashes in the URL you don't need those... Next to that your URL seems wrong, afaik you are using the plain sql server stuff and not the jdts stuff so I would expect a `jdbc:sqlserver` start for the url instead of what you have now.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for pointing `jtds` in the URL..That's where I was going  wrong.Actually we upgraded from Java 6 to Java 7 and as per  `Apache Commons DBCP 2` the compatible driver has to be `JDBC 4.1`.Previously I was using jtds and when the change happened I changed only driver class name and not the url...Also , as per your suggestion I removed the unnecessary slashes..Modified URL:jdbc:sqlserver://<ip_add>:<port>;database=<MyDB>;integratedSecurity=true; .. Thanks :)

Comment: @M.Deinum Please add this in answer to that I can accept and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your properties you have the following 2 properties

```
database.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
database.url=jdbc\:jtds\:sqlserver\://DB_ip:DB_Port/MyDB;instance=Some_Ins;integratedSecurity=true
```

It looks like you are using the plain sql server driver and not the jTDS one, so I would at least expect a URL without the `:jtds` part. Also there seem to be unnecessary slashes in the url. Change the `database.url` to the following

```
database.url=jdbc:sqlserver://DB_ip:DB_Port/MyDB;instance=Some_Ins;integratedSecurity=true
```

That should be a proper URL for the plain SQL Server driver.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same exception when my application can't connect to the database. So even if the URL is wrong, or the database name is wrong, or user / password combination is invalid - the same exception is thrown.

So I guess you should verify the connection properties - but be careful to set everything correct - starting with db server url, port, db name, user/pass.

Comment: URL is correct , verified and tried both windows authentication and uname and password (Same error in both the scenrios).

Comment: I missed something - the exception I am receiving is 'Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set'. I am using hibernate 4.3.11. But I found the exact place where that exception is thrown in the hibernate source code - you can do the same. Find the place where the exception is thrown and do some debugging in that area and maybe you will find out what is the problem. This is why I like to work with Hibernate + Spring because they are open source and I can debug the framework code when nothing else works.

Comment: Also maybe your stack trace is longer and you put only the top level exception + first caused by - I think you missed the last "caused by" (which should be an instance of org.hibernate.HibernateException)